# Red Heading Tag Error in VS Code - HTML/CSS

Tags: html

I'm a beginner in HTML and CSS, and am building a website using VS Code. I added a header tag, and it's red, and doesn't function.

Here is the code as raw text:

```
<body>
<div class="container"
    <header></header>    
    <main></main>
    <div class="cards"></div>
</div>
```

And here it is in VS Code as a screenshot [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5H3r.jpg)

Comment: You're missing a closing `>`...

Comment: Close your div tag properly

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a closing  `>` in the div opening. Please remember to close your tag properly.

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <header></header>    
    <main></main>
    <div class="cards"></div>
</div>
```